# is it possible to append the filename to the job-id of all jobs submitted to a CUPS printer?

Tags: printing, rhel7, printer, network-printer, cups

as the title suggests, I want to append the filenames of files I print to the actual job-ID in CUPS.
so if for instance i ran:
lp some-file.pdf

the job-ID would be: d00001-001somefile.pdf

The reason I want to do this is that the printer interacts with another piece of software that is hard coded to use the job-ID as file-name. this presents a problem as *some* printers don't recognize the files which end up being named something like:

d00021-001

which doesn't include a file extension.

I'm also interested to know whether this is completely impossible as that would be very helpful to rule this out as an option...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anything can be done if your company is willing to spend the money to maintain a private internal fork of a major open source project. It will probably cost a lot less to modify the custom LOB software that in theory your company is already maintaining.